# Are there any open datasets for commercial use?

Tags: data-request, data.gov

I am creating a bootcamp for data analyst and it's been 2 days I am looking for some good dataset fit for commercial use that I can use to create Tableau and Power BI tutorials. Even on kaggle some datasets are licensed as CC0 but when you track back the company the data was scrapped from, it states that the data shouldn't be used for commercial use (e.g Zomato dataset).

Are there any good data sources which I can use for this bootcamp's tutorial? Does the sample superstore dataset of Tableau can be used? But I think it does come under strict copyrights as well.

P.S I have emailed tons of people for permission and haven't heard back from anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Awesome public datasets collection will be a good start https://github.com/awesomedata/awesome-public-datasets

Also take a look at the major open data portals:

- EU https://data.europe.eu
- UK https://data.gov.uk
- US https://data.gov

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [data repo at NASA?](https://data.nasa.gov/)

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Would you mind linking to their license policy too?